# Can I use Breusch-Pagan test to a data that need correlation test later? or should I transform the data?

Tags: f-test, breusch-pagan

I did a homogeneity test using Levene test and the result said :
**"warning : in anova. lm(lm(resp~group))
ANOVA F-test on an essential perfect fit are unreliable"**

I want to test my data with the model (using Breusch-Pagan). I know the BP test is for regression, but I have no clue ( I'm a newbie).

But I need to do a correlation test later. Can I use the BP test? Or should I transform my data?

Cause I really need to know if my data is homogen/not...

Data is the accession number of the plant. I use accession number as a factor and block (repetitive) as a factor. With nine variables like the plant's diameter, etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to CV! Can you explain the data a bit more? _Data is the accession number of the plant._  What is an accession number? Which is the statistical unit? how many replications do you have, etc?

Comment: Hi.... The datas are genotypes of same plant (n=43) capsicum. so, all of them are named by numbers... I have 43 genotypes with 2 replications. The parameters/variables are stem length, stem diameter, day of flowering, fruit total, fruit length, fruit weight, stalk length of fruit, and productivity. In the end I have to know the correlation between parameters... Please comment, if you can help me... Ty

Comment: Oh... I forgot. I use the genotypes and replication as factors. Yup..